# Case of no response on approvals

Tags: approval-process, approval-step, approval-history

What flow would it be if user does not respond on approval/rejection request. I am creating a flow of approvals and rejections. What will happen to the flow when at some particular level user does not respond to approval/rejection request.Should I consider no response as a rejection?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to Business Team to decide whether no response is `no response` or `rejection`. Ideally `no response` should not be rejection. It also might be possible that approver is in leave and some other person may approve the request.

Better, if the approver is not responding after certain time period then you can setup a escalation mechanism to send a notification to his/her manager.

Think all this kind of scenarios and get them validated from Business.